# Импорт библиотек в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, модули

все ломаю голову над тем, как можно импортировать библиотеки/переменные в JS, нашел api по типу "Webkit", но и их использование не решило проблему.
Вот в чем проблема:
Пытаюсь импортировать файл
export js:
var pi = 3.14;

export default pi;
В файл import js:

import * as math from "export";

var a = math;

alert(math);

Но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:
"Access to script at 'file:///F:/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B/JS/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0/%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/import.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Может кто знает, как ее можно разрешить?

Comment: Обычно если мы хотим использовать экспорт и импорт из ES6 то нужно компилировать данный скрипт из es5 в es6.
В современных версиях браузера поддерживается возможность импорта файла, но нужно тегу скрипт указать тип module
<script type="module" src=""></script>

Comment: Вас на чистом английском написали, что модули не работают для протокола file: